# Can the general term my recurrence equations be written with Floor or Mod?

Tags: recursion

I want to know the formula for the general term of the following recurrence system. I guess it can be written with `Floor` or `Mod`. How can I find it?

```
RSolve[{a[n + 5] == a[n] + 6, a[1] == 1, a[2] == 3, a[3] == 2, a[4] == 1, a[5] == 1}, a[n], n]

DiscretePlot[-2 + (6 n)/5 + 
  2/5 Sqrt[28 + 53/Sqrt[5]] Sin[(2 n π)/5 - ArcTan[15/Sqrt[85 + 38 Sqrt[5]]]] + 
  2/5 Sqrt[28 - 53/Sqrt[5]] Sin[(4 n π)/5 - ArcTan[3 Sqrt[5 (85 + 38 Sqrt[5])]]],
 {n, 1, 20}]
```

**Updated**

I would like to have the formula for the general term without using recursion just as

```
RecurrenceTable[{y[n + 5] == y[n] + 1, 
  Sequence @@ Table[y[i] == i, {i, 5}]}, y, {n, 1, 30}]
```

can be written

```
n - 4 Floor[(n - 1)/5] /. n -> Range@30
```

Comment: Not sure how to obtain this programmatically, but it is `b[n_] := 6*(n - Mod[n, 5, 1])/5 + {1, 3, 2, 1, 1}.Map[DiscreteDelta, Mod[n, 5, 1] - Range[5]]`

Comment: @Daniel Please use backticks to offset code in comments.  Thanks.

Comment: I am curious about the reason for the edit, because although it suggests you are getting recursive formulas in the answers, none of the (three) replies so far use recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument of `DiscretePlot` is the sum of a linear function and explicitly periodic functions (`Sin`).  The periodicity can be expressed by the relationship

$$\sin(x) = \sin(\text{mod}(x, 2\pi)).$$

Whence, because $n$ is multiplied by $2\pi/5$ where it appears within the arguments of $\sin$, you can reduce the evaluation of the argument to values of $n$ between (say) $1$ and $5$ via the replacement

```
g = f /. Sin[x_] -> Sin[Mod[x, 2 \[Pi]]]
```

where `f` represents the function.  Noting that $n$ always appears divided by $5$, we can further simplify it by expressing $n$ in the form $5m + j$, $j=0, 1, 2, 3, 4$:

```
FullSimplify[g /. n -> 5 m + # , Assumptions -> m \[Element] Integers] & /@ Range[0, 4]
```

> {-5 + 6 m, 1 + 6 m, 3 + 6 m, 2 + 6 m, 1 + 6 m}

Because $m = \text{floor}\frac{n-1}{5}$ and the remainder is given by `Mod`, we can now proceed to write a formula in terms of `Floor` and `Mod`.

However, **none of this manipulation is necessary.**  The first line in the question exhibits `a` as a sum of a linear function (with slope $6/5$) and a periodic function of period $5$ defined by the values of $n$ from $1$ through $5$.  Both `Mod` and `Floor` naturally work with periods starting at $0$, whence we need to (a) offset `Mod` by $1$ and (b) subtract $1$ from $n$ before dividing by $5$ and applying `Floor`.  This immediately leads to the solution

```
a[1] = 1; a[2] = 3; a[3] = 2; a[4] = 1; a[5] = 1;
a[n_] /; n > 5 := a[Mod[n, 5, 1]] + 6 Floor[(n - 1)/5];
```

Looking at `DiscretePlot[a[n], {n, 1, 20}]` shows this to be exactly the same as the trigonometric formula.

Answer (score 3):

Pardon me of this is tautological but perhaps there will be some value to be found here.

Your sequence can be described as a linear recurrence:

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7}, 50] // 
  ListPlot[#, Filling -> Bottom] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Seeding this with symbolic values a simple pattern is apparent:

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, 31];
% ~Drop~ 6 ~Partition~ 5 // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f} = {1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7};

Table[
  With[{x = Quotient[n, 5]}, {b, c, d, e, f}[[1 + Mod[n, 5]]] - a x + f x],
  {n, -1, 48}
] // ListPlot[#, Filling -> Bottom] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The sequence is the same, though the index is offset by two.

Correcting that offset and converting this to a function:

```
fn[n_Integer] := {-5, 1, 3, 2, 1}[[1 + Mod[n, 5]]] + 6 Quotient[n, 5]

Array[fn, 50]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7, 9, 8, 7, 7, 13, 15, 14, 13, 13, 19, 21, 20, 19, 19, 25, 27,
>  26, 25, 25, 31, 33, 32, 31, 31, 37, 39, 38, 37, 37, 43, 45, 44, 43, 43, 49,
>  51, 50, 49, 49, 55, 57, 56, 55, 55}
> ```

Or:

```
fn[n_Integer] := {-5, 1, 3, 2, 1}[[1 + #2]] + 6 # & @@ QuotientRemainder[n, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
y[n_] := Ceiling[6/5 n] + Switch[Mod[n, 5], 0, -5, 1, -1, 2, 0, 3, -2, 4, -4];
```

Answer (score 2):

Also：

```
fn[n_] := 6 Floor[(n - 1)/5] + Mod[2 n^4 + 3 n^3 + 3 n^2 + 2 n + 1, 5]
Array[fn, 30]
DiscretePlot[fn[n], {n, 30}]
```