# How to deal with recursion formula in Mathematica?

Tags: recursion, algorithm

In engineering problems, I am always seeing many `recursion formula`.

For instance, In the book ***"The NURBS book"***, I discovered many *recursion formula*

- Fibonacci $$f(n+2)=f(n+1)+f(n)$$
- deCasteljau algorithm 
  $$\vec{P}_{k,i}(u_0)=(1-u_0)\vec{P}_{k-1,i}(u_0)+u_0\vec{P}_{k-1,i+1}(u_0)$$
- Horner

> [image]

And so on.

Previously, I know many *Mathematica* user used the solution as beow to code.

```
 fib[n_] := fib[n] = fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
 fib[1] = fib[2] = 1;

 fib[200]
```

> ```
>  280571172992510140037611932413038677189525
> ```

However, when `n` became larger, like `n=300`

```
fib[300]
```

> ```
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>
> ```

The *built-in* funcion `Fibonacci` can give the result normally.

```
Fibonacci[300]
```

> ```
> 222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600
> ```

*Question:*

Is it possible to have a `general(uniform) method`(Namely, like *Funcion Programing paradigm* like *Nest,NestList,FoldList*) to deal with these recursion formula in *Mathematica*?

#### Summarize

Firstly, thanks for the help of *igor Rivin,m_goldberg, bbpdqn*.

*(Efficiency test)*

```
IgorRivin = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}};
fibIgorRivin[n_] := MatrixPower[IgorRivin, n][[2, 1]]

fibIgorRivin[1000000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.2900166
> ```

```
fibGoldberg[n_Integer /; n > 0] := fibAux[1, 0, n]
fibAux[_, b_, 0] := b
fibAux[a_, b_, n_] := fibAux[a + b, a, n - 1]
```

> ```
>  $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>
> ```

```
fibUbpdqn[1] := 1;
fibUbpdqn[2] := 1;
fibUbpdqn[n_] := 
  First@Nest[{#[[1]] + #[[2]], #[[1]]} &, {1, 1}, n - 2]

fibUbpdqn[1000000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
>  15.2288711
> ```

```
Fibonacci[1000000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
>  0.2370136
> ```

Comment: You could simply set the `RecursionLimit` to a higher value. For example `$RecursionLimit = 1000`

Comment: With enough beer, you can tweak any recursive or iterative construct to do what you want. But why? The most reasonable structure to represent the Fib. progression is the recursive one.

Comment: But of course http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Comment: What version of _Mathematica_ are you using? In V10 on OS X and, I think V9 as well, the default value for `$RecursionLimit` is 1024.

Comment: @m_goldberg,V8, input: $RecursionLimit,output: 256

Comment: I recommend that you look at the function `RSolve` which can determine closed form representations for many recursive equations.

Comment: @BobHanlon, OK,:-)

Comment: Have a look at this approach if it can help [How to find the sum all even numbers of this sequence?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16856/how-to-find-the-sum-all-even-numbers-of-this-sequence/16860#16860).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A number of points:

First, if you need to compute several values of your sequence, your intial memo-ized implementation will NOT run into recursion limit problems.

Second, if you need to compute very few values, this method is extremely inefficient - the $n$-th Fibonacci number (or the $n$-th term of a linear recurrence in general) can be computed in $\log n$ operations. This can be done either by using linear algebra 
(the shift operator is an $n\times n$ matrix for an order $n$ recurrence) or the closed form solution (in terms of the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

For the matrix approach to Fibonacci:

```
fibmat = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}}
matfib[n_]:= MatrixPower[fibmat, n][[2, 1]]

matfib[200] // AbsoluteTiming
{0., 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525}

matfib[100000][[1]] // AbsoluteTiming
0.002000
```

As you see, this is much faster than the other ways *if you need single values*

Thirdly, once we are on the subject of closed form solutions, Mathematica does have `RSolve[]`/`RSolveValue[]`, which work fine for linear recurrences in my experience.

**Some words of explanation**

First question is: how to transform a recurrence into matrix multiplication? well, if you have the recurrence (for simplicity I use order 2, but this obviously works for any order):

$$ a_n = c_1 a_{n-1} + c_2 a_{n-2}$$ 
then moving forward in "time" $n$ transforms the pair $a_{n-1}, a_n$ into $a_n, a_{n+1} = c_1 a_n + c_2 a_{n-1},$ so that this corresponds to acting on the vector $\begin{pmatrix} a_{n-1}\\a_n\end{pmatrix}$ by the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1\\
c_2 && c_1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So, computing the $n$th term of the recurrence corresponds to raising the matrix to the $n$th power (starting with the initial conditions).

Now, computing $x^n$ (where $x$ is a number *or* a matrix can be done by repeated squaring, and takes $O(\log n)$ multiplications. Of course, if you want to know the exact answer, the multiplications will take longer once you get further along, but this is not an issue when you are dealing with floating point numbers (you never increase the precision), and an amusing computation shows that this is a big win for exact integer computation IF asymptotically fast integer arithmetic is used (as it is in Mathematica).

I am 99% certain that this is the algorithm used for `Fibonacci[]` (of course it is even faster than what I did, since it is hardcoded in C, but if you have your own favorite recurrence, this is not going to be true.

Comment: +1,As the n becoming larger and larger ,like `1000000`,your alogrithm is fastest.:-),BTW, could you give a explanation to your algorithm? Thanks !!

Comment: @Tangshutao see the edit...

Answer (score 17):

If you can rewrite the recursion to be tail recursive, you will not run into recursion limits.

Here is an example of a tail-recursive implementation of factorial.

```
factorial[1, val_: 1] = val;
factorial[k_Integer /; k > 1, val_: 1] := factorial[k - 1, k val]

factorial /@ Range[10]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}
> ```

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20}, factorial[42]]
```

> ```
> 1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000
> ```

Note that in the last case, although the recursion limit was reduced to 20, no `$RecursionLimit::reclim:` message is emitted.

#### Update

By popular demand; i.e., belisarius' request.

```
fib[n_Integer /; n > 0] := fibAux[1, 0, n]
fibAux[_, b_, 0] := b
fibAux[a_, b_, n_] := fibAux[a + b, a, n - 1]

fib /@ Range[20]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765}
> ```

```
Block[{$RecursionLimit = 20}, fib[200]]
```

> ```
> 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525
> ```

The general principle behind the two examples I've given is that the recursive function's argument sequence must carry all the state information needed at each step in the process.

---

#### References

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

[What tools can help in realizing tail recursion?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21746/3066)

Comment: Perhaps posting the tail recursive code for the Fibonacci numbers would be a beau geste towards the OP :).... (and me)

Comment: +1, Powerful, `fib[800]` can be caculated immediately when `$RecursionLimit = 256`. I think I can apply this idea to other problem.:-) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just approaches using `Nest`:

Fibonacci:

```
fi[1] := 1;
fi[2] := 1;
fi[n_] := First@Nest[{#[[1]] + #[[2]], #[[1]]} &, {1, 1}, n - 2]
```

Note:

```
Timing[fi[200]]
```

yields:

> {0., 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525}

or (really the same):

```
fb[1] := 1;
fb[2] := 1;
fb[n_] := First@Nest[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}.# &, {1, 1}, n - 2]
```

yields same

Or factorial:

```
fact[n_] :=  First@Nest[{#[[1]] #[[2]], #[[2]] - 1} &, {n, n - 1}, n - 1]
```

(noting for all these Mathematica has implementations or you could use e.g. `Times@@Range[n]` and define for `n=0`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Fibonacci sequence is your example you should see:

- [Fibonacci Sequence Generator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31593/121)

As described there you can also make use of [`LinearRecurrence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearRecurrence.html):

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 1}, {1, 1}, 15]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610}
> ```

The syntax is simple and fairly general.  It is comparatively fast for generating a complete sequence but it is not fast for finding single values.

In [this earlier Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294376/618728) Daniel Lichtblau gave the [`MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixPower.html) method that Igor Rivin describes.  At that time I wrote a function to convert between the `LinearRecurrence` syntax and the `MatrixPower` equivalent:

```
linRec[r_, c_, i_] /; i <= Length@c := c[[i]]

linRec[r_, c_, i_] /; Length[r] == Length[c] :=
  With[{kern = Rest@IdentityMatrix[Length@r] ~Join~ {Reverse@r}},
    Last[MatrixPower[kern, i - Length@r]].c
  ]
```

Now:

```
linRec[{1, 1}, {1, 1}, 15]
```

> ```
> 610
> ```

And also:

```
LinearRecurrence[{-1, -1, 2, 3, 2}, {6, 8, 9, -9, -3}, {500}]

linRec[{-1, -1, 2, 3, 2}, {6, 8, 9, -9, -3}, 500]
```

> ```
> {12519024244418274297611984359547397636366092718206074485347827784856486463673}
>
> 12519024244418274297611984359547397636366092718206074485347827784856486463673
> ```

The `MatrixPower` method is far faster than `LinearRecurrence` for a single value when the kernel is small:

```
LinearRecurrence[{-1, -1, 2, 3, 2}, {6, 8, 9, -9, -3}, {500000}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
linRec[{-1, -1, 2, 3, 2}, {6, 8, 9, -9, -3}, 500000]             // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 6.290360
>
> 0.030002
> ```

However you should be aware that with very large kernels it is *slower* than `LinearRecurrence`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
a = RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, {2, 200}];  (* kernel length 200 *)

LinearRecurrence[##, {500}] & @@ a // AbsoluteTiming // First
linRec[##, 500] & @@ a             // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.049003
>
> 0.362021
> ```

In such cases the [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nest.html) method [I proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5295075/618728) in that old StackExchange Q&A is better:

```
lr[a_, b_, n_Integer] := First@Nest[Append[Rest@#, a.#] &, b, n - 1]

lr[##, 500] & @@ a // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.017001
> ```

You can also generate the full sequence by using [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html) if desired.

---

Related:

- [Can the general term my recurrence equations be written with Floor or Mod?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18295/121)
- [How can I get the general term of this recurrence equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18804/121)

---

### Addendum

You asked about the difference between generating a complete sequence and finding single values.

- In some cases it is possible to directly calculate a single value, bypassing the recursion entirely.  For example a Fibonacci number may be calculated using:

  ```
    Round[(GoldenRatio^(2 #) - (-1)^#)/(Sqrt[5] GoldenRatio^#)] &
  ```

  This is fast (though not as fast as MatrixPower) for a single value, but it would be very slow to calculate every value in the sequence using this function.
- The use of `MatrixPower` may appear iterative but I do not believe this is actually the case.  Although I am not familiar with the algorithm used I would not expect all intermediate values to be generated in its calculation, therefore it is unsuited to generating the full sequence.
- Even if a method such as `Nest` ostensibly generates all the values in the sequence up to *n* the overhead (and memory consumption) of accumulating these values may larger than the computation itself, therefore it would be foolish to use e.g. `NestList` and then extract the last value.

Comment: I have a question: what's the difference between `generating a complete sequence` and  `finding single values`?I'm always thinking that: 1,`generating a complete sequence` 2, Exacting the `single values` from the `complete sequence`.@Mr.Wizard, Could you explain it to me?Thanks sincerely!!:-)

Comment: @Tangshutao I am too sleepy tonight but I will try to add a few comments on that tomorrow.

Comment: I'm so sorry,@Mr.Wizard I forgoit the problem timezone beteen USA and China.

Comment: @ShutaoTang Please see the **Addendum**.  I hope that I understood your question and that you find my comments useful.

Answer (score 2):

#### My thought about recursion formula  this two weeks:

- For recursion formula $a_{n}=c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2}\quad (n \geq 2)$

Thanks for @IgorRivin's explanation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
c_2 & c_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n-2}\\
a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=\ldots
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
c_2 & c_1
\end{bmatrix}^{n-2}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
=A^{n-2}\beta
$$

So for `fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`:

```
fib[n_Integer]:=
  Last@(MatrixPower[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, n - 2].{1, 1})
```

Test:

```
Fibonacci[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0030002, Null}
> ```

```
fib[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0040002, Null}
> ```

```
matfib[100000]; // AbsoluteTiming (*Igor Rivin*)
```

> ```
> {0.0030002, Null}
> ```

- deCasteljau algorithm

  $$\vec{P}_{k,i}(u_0)=\color{red}{(1-u_0)}\vec{P}_{k-1,i}(u_0)+\color{red}{(u_0)}\vec{P}_{k-1,i+1}(u_0)$$

[image]

I discovered occationly a *built-in* function [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html?q=MovingAverage)
which can realize the *deCasteljau algorithm*

<strike>deCasteljau[pts : {{_, *} ..}, u0*] := 
      Prepend[
        NestList[
         MovingAverage[#, {2, 3}] &, MovingAverage[pts, {1 - u0, u0}], Length@pts -2],pts]</strike>

```
 deCasteljau[pts : {{_, _} ..}, u0_] := 
   NestList[MovingAverage[#, {1 - u0, u0}] &, pts, Length@pts - 1]
```

test:

```
deCasteljau[{{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}, 2/5]
```

> ```
>   {{{0, 0}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 0}}, {{4/5, 8/5}, {14/5, 22/5}, {24/5, 3}}, 
>      {{8/5, 68/25}, {18/5, 96/25}}, {{12/5, 396/125}}}
> ```

This method can avoid using `P[k_, i_, u0_] := (1 - u0) P[k - 1, i, u0] + u0 P[k - 1, i + 1, u0]`

- Horner algorithm

Using [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html?q=Fold)

```
 horner[coeffi_, x_Symbol] := 
   x #[[1]] + #[[2]] &@
     Fold[{x #[[1]] + #[[2]], #2} &, Take[coeffi, -2], Reverse@Drop[coeffi, -2]]
```

Test:

```
horner[{a0, a1, a2, a3, a4}, x]
```

> ```
>  a0 + x (a1 + x (a2 + x (a4 + a3 x)))
> ```

#### Summarize

Sometimes, for me, using `recursion formula` in *Mathematica* can easily lead to *Mathematica* `no responding`(in this condition, I cannot use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>,  command to abort caculation)

So it is necesary for me to try to using `constructional operation` to replace recursion formula.

[image]