# Plotting two recursive functions

Tags: plotting, recursion

I'm trying to plot two recursive functions (p and θ) on a map. So far I have:

```
θ0 = Pi/2;
p0 = 0;
α = 0.1;
β = 1;

θ[j_] := θ[j] = θ[j - 1] + β*p[j - 1];
p[j_] := p[j] = 
   p[j - 1] - α*Sin[θ[j - 1] + β*p[j - 1]];
θ[0] = θ0;
p[0] = p0;
```

How can I plot `p[j]` against `θ[j]` for `0 <= j <= 100`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html):

```
DiscretePlot[{θ[j], p[j]}, {j, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Or perhaps you want something like this?:

```
ListPlot @ Table[{θ[j], p[j]}, {j, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Another method is to use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) after sufficiently coercing the input, e.g.:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := {θ[#], p[#]} & @ Round @ x

ParametricPlot[f[j], {j, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

(Aspect ratio may be controlled with the [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) option.)

Comment: that plots p and θ by j. I need to plot p by θ (for every matching j) as it if were a phase space

Comment: @Geo You mean you want `p` on one axis and `θ` on the other?

Comment: yeah. sorry my not being so clear on the question.

Comment: @Geo Please see update.

Comment: ahh that's it. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Geo You're welcome.  One point: you said "for every matching j" but all points match.  Do you have a case where they do not?  You may need to filter the result of `Table` using e.g. `Cases` or `Select`.  Let me know if you need help.

Comment: ehh english not my mother language. What I meant was (p1,θ1), (p2,θ2) and so on. what you did is completely correct. In case I have any trouble I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: @Geo Okay, no problem.  I added another method for your interest.

Answer (score 3):

A proposal using Functional paradigm to avoid recursive functions.

```
data=
 With[{α = .1, β = 1},
   NestList[
    {#[[1]] + β #[[2]], #[[2]] - α Sin[#[[1]] + β #[[2]]]} &,
    {Pi/2, 0}, 100]];

ListPlot[data]
```

> [image]

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer the question it does show a good technique; `NestList` is often faster and simpler than recursion in *Mathematica*.  By the way this can also be written: `With[{α = .1, β = 1}, NestList[{# + β #2, #2 - α Sin[# + β #2]} & @@ # &, {Pi/2, 0}, 100]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,+1, your solution is indeed I need! I am alway writing the code: `With[{α = .1, β = 1}, NestList[{# + β #2, #2 - α Sin[# + β #2]} & , [Pi/2, 0], 100]]` before. Thanks sir!

Comment: You're welcome.  Another method you might like:  `With[{α = .1, β = 1}, NestList[# /. {x_, y_} :> {x + β y, y - α Sin[x + β y]} &, {Pi/2, 0}, 100]]` as described here: [(8399)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121).  This can be more readable than an excessive number of `#*` parameters.

Comment: that's interesting. I will try using this for plotting the results for different initial conditions on the same graph. thanks

Comment: @Geo,see [here]( http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61050/how-to-deal-with-recursion-formula-in-mathematica/61200noredirect=1#comment177723_61200)，my answer is at last.