# How to define multiple functions using a for command

Tags: function-construction

Let's say I want to plot 10 graphs of those following [functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63524/plotting-two-recursive-functions). 
Since they are recursive functions, I cant make a table with 10 different initial conditions because Mathematica stores each value individually.

Then, I could define p1...p10 and θ1...θ10 manually and just make a `Show[graph1...graph10]`

However, how can I define the functions in an fast way doing something like that:

```
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++;
 θi[j_] := θi[j] = θi[j - 1] + β*pi[j - 1];
 pi[j_] := pi[j] = pi[j - 1] - α*Sin[θi[j - 1] + β*pi[j - 1]];
 θi[0] = Pi/4+i/10; 
 pi[0] = 0.8-i/10;
 graphi = ListPlot[Table[{θi[j], pi[j]}, {j, 0, 100}], AxesLabel -> {"θ(j)", "p(j)"}]]
```

so I can join the functions plot in a `Show` later?

Comment: I´d recommend putting together a `Module` for such things - take a look at the docs, there are many examples.

Comment: `th[i_][j_] := th[i][j] = th[i][j - 1] + \[Beta] p[i][j - 1];
p[i_][j_] := 
  p[i][j] = 
   th[i][j - 1] - \[Alpha] Sin[th[i][j - 1]] + \[Beta] p[i][j - 1];
th[i_][0] := Pi/4 + i/10;
p[i_][0] := .8 - i/10;
\[Alpha] = \[Beta] = .01;`

Comment: @YvesKlett I will take a look. thanks
Kuba that could help me. interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ought to set up functions that are indexed by `i`, not just looped through and reusing the same names. Why use `θi` when you could use `θ[i]`?

```
α=0.2;β=0.1;
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
 θ[i][j_] := θ[i][j] = θ[i][j - 1] + β*p[i][j - 1];
 p[i][j_] := p[i][j] = p[i][j - 1] - α*Sin[θ[i][j - 1] + β*p[i][j - 1]];
 θ[i][0] = Pi/4+i/10; 
 p[i][0] = 0.8-i/10;
 graph[i] = ListPlot[
  Table[{θ[i][j], p[i][j]}, {j, 0, 100}],
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[{1 - i/10, i/15, i/10}]
 ]
]
```

All I did was make every instance of `i` in a variable name into a parameter `[i]`. Also watch out! You have a semicolon after `i++` when you should have a comma. And the important plot option, color, is here, while the axes labels are relegated to the `Show` command (below).

If you want these to vary with α and β, I suggest you also include them as arguments, e.g. `θ[i][α_,β_,j_]` or similar.

I don't want to change your code too much, so I mostly just replaced `i` with `[i]`. However, you could also avoid the use of a loop entirely (if you're really interested, comment and I can follow up) because now you are just defining ten separate functions.

Anyway, after that, all you need is:

```
Show[Table[graph[i], {i, 1, 9}],
 AxesLabel -> {"θ(j)", "p(j)"}, PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: final output plot]

I added the color options so that you can see which is which. With these parameter values they look like ellipses. I also started by setting values for your parameters. If they are not numerical, you can't plot them, so I went ahead and assumed you have them. Note that in addition to not giving you an actual graph, if α and β are symbolic, the recursion becomes a symbolic nightmare computing a table of 100 recursions of some symbolic expression.

Comment: thanks. i didn't know we could use p[i][j_]. what does exactly the first argument ([i]) means in an function?

Comment: @Geo My thoughts on that construct are [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121).  In this case I believe one could also have used `θ[i, j_] :=` but I think `θ[i][j_]` is more clear.

Comment: Mathematica has two different things when it comes to brackets. You can define something with an index, like `x[1]=3;x[2]=2;x[3]=q;x[4]=3q;` so that `Sum[x[i],{i,1,4}]` will give you `5+4q`. This is just on-the-spot, and the `i` doesn't stand for any special type of input -- if a value of `i` is used that is "unknown" in some way, Mathematica leaves `x[i]` unevaluated. But if you define a function `x[i_]=i^2`, then Mathematica has a symbolic understanding that `x` is a function. For us, `i` is not so much an input as an index for our functions. Generally I prefer `f[a][x]` to allow `f[a]'[x]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Table` if you [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) within the loop:

```
α = 0.2; β = 0.1;

Table[
  Clear[θi, pi];
  θi[j_] := θi[j] = θi[j - 1] + β*pi[j - 1];
  pi[j_] := pi[j] = pi[j - 1] - α*Sin[θi[j - 1] + β*pi[j - 1]];
  θi[0] = Pi/4 + i/10;
  pi[0] = 0.8 - i/10;
  Table[{θi[j], pi[j]}, {j, 0, 100}],
  {i, 10}
] // ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"θ(j)", "p(j)"}] &
```

Using `NestList` makes all this simpler however:

```
α = 0.2; β = 0.1;

Table[
  NestList[
    {# + β #2, #2 - α*Sin[# + β #2]} & @@ # &,
    {Pi/4 + i/10, 0.8 - i/10},
    100
  ],
  {i, 10}
] // ListPlot[#, AxesLabel -> {"θ(j)", "p(j)"}] &
```

[image]

Although not general you can even utilize the listability (vector computation) of all constituent operations in your functions to turn the problem inside out:

```
ListPlot[
  NestList[{# + β #2, #2 - α*Sin[# + β #2]} & @@ # &,
    {Pi/4 + #/10, 0.8 - #/10} & @ Range @ 10, 100] ~Transpose~ {2, 3, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"θ(j)", "p(j)"}
]
```

Comment: This is, more or less, what I would have recommended when I mentioned "you could also avoid the use of a loop entirely." The data is, essentially, one big table. I'll leave it to Mr.Wizard, who's much more adept at `NestList` than I am.

Comment: @Kellen Thanks!  By the way I voted for your answer. :-)