# Plotting system of recursive sequences

Tags: plotting, difference-equations

If I have a system of recursive sequences like

```
x[n+1]=2x[n]+5(y[n])^2

y[n+1]=.5x[n]-3(y[n])^2
```

How can I plot it as a curves `{x[n],n}` and `{y[n],n}` in the same figure??
When I work with this code, I get the error as in the image[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IHuS.png)

Comment: Check this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63524/plotting-two-recursive-functions?rq=1

Comment: What initial conditions, `{x[1], y[1]} do you wish?

Comment: Thank you very much!
"But when I copied this code  in Mathematica 7. I get the error message:
ListLinePlot::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in ListLinePlot[{{1.,22.,705.25},{2.,-11.5,-385.75}},<<4>>,PlotLegends->{x,y}]. >>"

Comment: @Raafat Load the package. ``<< PlotLegends` ``

Comment: @Raafat *Mathematica 7* does not have `PlotLegends`; you will need to load the package as MMM says but also use `PlotLegend` with no `s`, and parameters for the two options are not the same.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wizard, it is with no "s".

Answer (score 3):

`RecurrenceTable` will be useful here. Note, I choose random initial conditions.

```
sol = RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 2  x[n] + 5 (y[n])^2, 
y[n + 1] == 0.5  x[n] - 3 (y[n])^2, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2}, {x, 
y}, {n, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];

ListLinePlot[Transpose@sol, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], 
   Directive[Blue, AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}]]}, Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 22, Bold] & /@ {"n", ""}), 
 PlotLegends -> {x,  y}]
```

[image]

You can also use @David G. Stork [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79532/plotting-non-linear-recursive-sequence/79538#79538).

```
x[n_] := 2  x[n - 1] + 5 (y[n - 1])^2;  
y[n_] := 0.5  x[n - 1] - 3 (y[n - 1])^2;
x[0] := 1;    
y[0] := 2;    
ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{x[n], y[n]}, {n, 0, 2}], 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}]
```

Comment: No, but I have  an error when i do!

Comment: @Raafat Doing what produces an error?

Comment: I have copied the code and use it in mathematica. But it gives the error message:
" ListLinePlot::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in ListLinePlot[{{1,22,705.25},{2,-11.5,-385.75}},PlotLegends->{x,y}]. >>"

Comment: Thank you for help! the code does work. But without "PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}"!! Do you have a solution to that ?!

Comment: @Raafat load the package. << PlotLegends`

Comment: @Raafat You should also recheck your difference equations or share your odes here because the image you tried to include to the answer is hard to be produced with this current approach.

Comment: I have edited the question, and wish to help me!

Comment: @Raafat I already told you what to do. load the package. << PlotLegends`

Comment: OK! Thank you very much.