# How can I make a Tribonacci sequence in the form of a list?

Tags: recursion, integer-sequence

How can I  make a `Tribonacci` sequence that is in listing form? it suppose to look like the `Fibonacci` sequence but I couldn't get the same result with `Tribonacci`.[image]

```
Array[Fibonacci, 9]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34}
> ```

```
Array[Tribonacci, 9]
```

> ```
> {Tribonacci[1], Tribonacci[2], Tribonacci[3], Tribonacci[4], 
>  Tribonacci[5], Tribonacci[6], Tribonacci[7], Tribonacci[8], Tribonacci[9]}
> ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Is Tribonacci defined?

First you should notice that `Tribonacci` is not already defined by *Mathematica*. Compare the defined [`Fibonacci`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci.html)

```
?Fibonacci
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with

```
?Tribonacci
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could have guessed by the color of the function in the front-end display, black for defined and blue for undefined.

### Fibonacci n-Step Number

Now we can define the even more general [Fibonacci n-Step Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html). We will use [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

```
ClearAll[FnStepN];
FnStepN[0, n_] = 0; FnStepN[1, n_] = 1; FnStepN[2, n_] = 1;

FnStepN[k_Integer, n_Integer] := 
 FnStepN[k, n] = Sum[FnStepN[k - i, n], {i, 1, Min[k, n]}]


TableForm[
 Table[FnStepN[k, n], {n, 10}, {k, 10}]
 , TableHeadings -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**EDIT**

After the answer by @Mr.Wizard here is an alternative implementation of *Fibonacci n-Step Number* but giving the whole list

```
FibStepN[k_Integer, n_Integer] := Take[
  LinearRecurrence[
   Table[1, {n}]
   , PadLeft[{1, 1}, n]
   , k + n - 2
   ]
  , -k]
```

Or

```
FibStepN[k_Integer, n_Integer] := 
 Nest[Append[#, Total[Take[#, -Min[n, Length[#]]]]] &, {1, 1}, k - 2]
```

### Tribonacci

Now `Tribonacci` is just a special case of `FnStepN`

```
Tribonacci[k_] = FnStepN[k, 3]

Array[Tribonacci, 11]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274}

For performance look at this other [similar answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31594/10397).

Comment: What should I change in order to have this kind of result for lucas n-step sequence? aside from changing FnStepN into LnStepN.

Comment: @Charles  I have provided an answer to your question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96908/10397)

Answer (score 12):

[`LinearRecurrence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearRecurrence.html) is useful here:

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, 9]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81}
> ```

Related:

- [Fibonacci Sequence Generator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31593/121)
- [How to deal with recursion formula in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61050/how-to-deal-with-recursion-formula-in-mathematica/61200#61200)

Comment: Your answer is shifted `{1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149}`  `->`  `{0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81}`

Comment: @rhermans I did not see that as a sufficiently difficult problem to address, but one can use e.g. `Rest` or `LinearRecurrence[{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 10}]` as he sees fit.  *Oh*, or use `LinearRecurrence[{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, 9]` which is probably what you were getting at.  :-o  I'll edit that in.

Comment: This is the right way, IMO...+1

Answer (score 10):

As noted by the Wizard, `LinearRecurrence[]` is an excellent way to handle integer sequences based on linear difference equations. Had that mechanism not been available, one can exploit the relationship between linear recurrences and powers of the Frobenius companion matrix of the recurrence's characteristic polynomial:

```
SetAttributes[Tribonacci, Listable];
Tribonacci[0] = 0;
Tribonacci[1] = Tribonacci[2] = 1;
Tribonacci[k_Integer?Positive] :=
           MatrixPower[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, k - 2, {1, 1, 0}][[1]]
```

where I used the "action" form of `MatrixPower[]`.

Some insight into how this works can be seen by looking at the associated matrix in two different ways. Let

$$\mathbf F=\begin{pmatrix}1&\cdots&&1\\1&&&\\&\ddots&&\\&&1&\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf S+\mathbf e_1\mathbf e^\top$$

where $\mathbf S$ is the "shift matrix" (the matrix that transforms $\begin{pmatrix}c_1&\cdots&c_n\end{pmatrix}^\top$ to $\begin{pmatrix}0&c_1&\cdots&c_{k-1}\end{pmatrix}^\top$, $\mathbf e$ is `ConstantArray[1, k]` in *Mathematica* notation, and $\mathbf e_1$ is `UnitVector[k, 1]` in *Mathematica* notation. This particular decomposition shows how the linear recurrence proceeds: the shift matrix moves the contents of the column vector containing the initial conditions downward, and the correction term sets up the appropriate linear combination of the vector's components.

The other way to look at $\mathbf F$ is to note that it is, as I mentioned earlier, the Frobenius companion matrix of $x^k-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} x^j$, which is the characteristic polynomial of the linear recurrence $F_n=\sum_{j=1}^k F_{n-j}$. $\mathbf F$ thus has the eigendecomposition

$$\mathbf F=\mathbf V\begin{pmatrix}x_1&&\\&\ddots&\\&&x_k\end{pmatrix}\mathbf V^{-1}$$

and the $x_j$ are the $k$ roots of the characteristic polynomial. $\mathbf F^n$ thus has the eigendecomposition

$$\mathbf F^n=\mathbf V\begin{pmatrix}x_1^n&&\\&\ddots&\\&&x_k^n\end{pmatrix}\mathbf V^{-1}$$

and the entire business is revealed to be equivalent to taking appropriate linear combinations of the $x_j^n$.

---

### Extra credit

The machinery behind `DifferenceRoot[]` can of course be used to implement the general $k$-nacci number. Witness the following:

```
knacci[k_Integer?Positive] := knacci[k] = 
       DifferenceRoot[Function @@
                      {{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, 
                       Prepend[Thread[(\[FormalY] /@ {1, 2}) == 1] ~Join~
                               Thread[(\[FormalY] /@ Range[3 - k, 0]) == 0],
                               \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] ==
                               Sum[\[FormalY][\[FormalN] - K], {K, 1, k}]]}]
```

after which, one can do `Tribonacci = knacci[3]`.

Still another possibility is to use `SeriesCoefficient[]` on the generating function:

```
knacci[k_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?NonNegative] := 
       SeriesCoefficient[(\[FormalX] (1 - \[FormalX]))/
                         (1 - 2 \[FormalX] + \[FormalX]^(k + 1)), {\[FormalX], 0, n}]
```

---

Carrying the generating function idea further along, one could consider using
[Cauchy's differentiation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) with an appropriate anticlockwise contour to evaluate $k$-nacci numbers. Here is one such routine based on this idea:

```
SetAttributes[knacci, Listable]
knacci[k_Integer?Positive, n_?NumericQ] := 
       Re[NIntegrate[(1 - z)/((1 - 2 z + z^(k + 1)) z^n),
                     {z, -1/2, -I/2, 1/2, I/2, -1/2}]/(2 π I)]
```

Comment: FWIW I did reference this in the last link in my answer, but +1 of course.

Comment: I saw that. :) The missing piece was to use the "action" form instead of explicitly forming the power before multiplying. The version using `Nest[]` on an appropriate starting vector does sidestep the problem.

Comment: The first idea comes to my mind is `MatrixPower` when I see the definion of Enrique Pérez Herrero. Please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61050/how-to-deal-with-recursion-formula-in-mathematica/61068#61068)

Comment: J.M, could you add the theroy about why you using the `MatrixPower `? I think it is necessary for others  understand your implementation easily:)

Comment: @Shutao, maybe later; that's a rather long discussion...

Comment: Recurrence in disguise, so +1 mandatory. Good to see you back.

Comment: Fixed @Karsten, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
Tribonacci[0] := 0;
Tribonacci[1] := 1;
Tribonacci[2] := 1;
Tribonacci[3] := 2;
Tribonacci[n_] := 
Tribonacci[n] = 
Tribonacci[n - 1] + Tribonacci[n - 2] + Tribonacci[n - 3];
Array[Tribonacci, 9]
(* {1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81} *)
```

**An alternate expression** can be found in https://oeis.org/A000073:

```
CoefficientList[Series[x^2/(1 - x - x^2 - x^3), {x, 0, 50}], x]
```

Also you can find more information about:  `Tribonacci[n] - Fibonacci[n]`, in:
https://oeis.org/A000100

**Even more...**

```
a = (19 + 3*Sqrt[33])^(1/3);
b = (19 - 3*Sqrt[33])^(1/3);
Trib[n_] := Round[3*((a + b + 1)/3)^(n + 1)/(a^2 + b^2 + 4)]
Table[Trib[n] - Tribonacci[n], {n, 1, 20}]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html

Answer (score 7):

If -- like with [`Fibonacci`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci.html) -- you want `Tribonacci` defined more generally than just for integer arguments, use [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html).

```
Clear[Tribonacci];
Tribonacci[n_] = Tribonacci[n] /. RSolve[{Tribonacci[0] == 0,
        Tribonacci[1] == 1,
        Tribonacci[2] == 1,
        Tribonacci[n] == 
         Tribonacci[n - 1] + Tribonacci[n - 2] + Tribonacci[n - 3]}, 
       Tribonacci[n], n][[1]] // ToRadicals // Simplify;
Tribonacci[n_Integer] :=
  Tribonacci[N[n]] // Chop // Round;
```

The last definition for integer arguments is added to speed up the calculations. To get a simple result for integers would generally require use of [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) of a very complicated expression and would be quite slow. The numerical approximation is much faster but requires [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) to remove imaginary artifacts caused by use of machine precision and [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html) to give the exact solution desired.

```
Tribonacci /@ Range[0, 10]

(*  {0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149}  *)

Show[
 Plot[Tribonacci[n], {n, -10, 10}],
 DiscretePlot[Tribonacci[n], {n, -10, 8},
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: As it turns out, you could also use `FunctionExpand[DifferenceRoot[(* stuff *)][n]]` to derive explicit expressions for $k$-nacci numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`SequenceFold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceFold.html)

```
tribonacci[n_] := SequenceFold[Plus, {1, 1, 2}, ConstantArray[0, n - 3]]
tribonacci[1] = tribonacci[2] = 1;

Array[tribonacci, 9]
```

$\ $`{1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81}`

or [`SequenceFoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceFoldList.html)

```
tribonacciList[n_] := SequenceFoldList[Plus, {1, 1, 2}, ConstantArray[0, n - 3]]
tribonacciList[1] = {1};
tribonacciList[2] = {1, 1};

tribonacciList[9]
```

$\ $`{1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81}`

---

Benchmark table of the `AbsoluteTiming`s for the calculation of a list of the first 9 and 5000 Tribonacci numers:

[image]

Comment: Would you add benchmarks for these?  I am curious to know how these functions (`SequenceFold` family) perform and I do not have v10.2.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll put that on my list for tomorrow. But I can already say that my performance expectations are relatively low, as these functions are implemented as high level functions using `Fold` and `FoldList`, respectively.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard compared to the other methods, using `SequenceFoldList` actually performs really good.

Answer (score 5):

Additional theory explanation for [J.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96654/how-can-i-make-a-tribonacci-sequence-in-the-form-of-a-list/96667#96667)

The definition of `Tribonacci[]` can be written as below:

$$a_{n+3}=a_n+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$$

then

we could construct the following recursive matrix formula

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+3}\\
a_{n+2}\\
a_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 && 1\\
1 && 0 && 0\\
0 && 1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+2}\\
a_{n+1}\\
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
=A^2\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1}\\
a_{n}\\
a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}=\cdots=
A^{n+1}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{2}\\
a_{1}\\
a_{0}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where,

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 && 1 && 1\\
1 && 0 && 0\\
0 && 1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: Your companion matrix is backwards; the subdiagonal goes from left to right.

Comment: @J.M. OK, I made a mistake. THX:)

Answer (score 4):

**Tail recursive** implementation

```
tribo[n_, a_, b_, c_] := tribo[n - 1, b, c, a + b + c]
tribo[0, a_, b_, c_] := a
tribo[n_] := tribo[n, 0, 1, 1]

Array[tribo, 9] // AbsoluteTiming
```

$\ $`{0.0000928937, {1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81}}`

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
 tribo~Array~5000; // AbsoluteTiming // First]
```

$\ $`25.2784`

And for a faster generation of Tribonacci lists

```
triboList[n_, a_, b_, c_] := triboList[n - 1, Sow[b], c, a + b + c]
triboList[1, a_, b_, c_] := Sow[b]
triboList[n_] := Reap[triboList[n, 0, 1, 1]][[2, 1]]

triboList[9] // AbsoluteTiming
```

$\ $`{0.0000497884, {1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81}}`

```
Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity},
 triboList[5000]; // AbsoluteTiming // First]
```

$\ $`0.0129951`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

`ContinuedFraction[Root[#^3-#^2-#-1]&,1],100]`

or
`Convergents[N[Convergents[N[t]]]]`

From Mathworld:

The ratio of adjacent terms tends to the positive real root (x^3-x^2-x-1)_1, namely 1.83929... (OEIS A058265), sometimes known as the tribonacci constant.

Comment: There is a typographical error here; would you try to fix it please?  I'd like to see this working.

Comment: I'm sure there's more than just a typographical error, but try: ContinuedFraction[N[Root[#^3-#^2-#-1]&,1]],100]

Comment: Unfortunately, the approach here is flawed; the number whose simple CF expansion contains the tribonacci numbers is approximately `1.6914979485021664824009037684992342805376592458272`, which is quite far from the value of `Root[#^3 - #^2 - # - 1 &, 1]` (`1.8392867552141611325518525646532866004241787460976`).