# How do I determine the 15th Lucas term in the 3rd order?

Tags: recursion, integer-sequence

I want to implement the **Lucas n-Step Number**.

This command taken from [**here**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96660/193) doesn't seem to work, am I using the right command?[image]

```
ClearAll[LnStepN];
LnStepN[2, n_] = 0; LnStepN[1, n_] = 1; LnStepN[3, n_] = 1;

LnStepN[k_Integer, n_Integer] := 
 LnStepN[k, n] = Sum[LnStepN[k - i, n], {i, 1, Min[k, n]}]
```

Comment: Can you not add the code in plain text? This would make people more likely to help you.

Comment: Its from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96660/10397). It does work for me :)

Comment: @rhermans Notice that the code you added does NOT have the same starting conditions as the code the OP posted. I think therein lies the problem...

Comment: @MarcoB fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the definition from [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/),  the "[Lucas n-Step Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lucasn-StepNumber.html)" is define by:

```
ClearAll[LnStepN];
LnStepN[k_, n_] := -1 /; k < 0;
LnStepN[0, n_] = n;
LnStepN[1, n_] = 1;
LnStepN[k_Integer, n_Integer] := 
 LnStepN[k, n] = Sum[LnStepN[k - i, n], {i, 1, n}]
```

To verify the solution:

```
Table[
  LnStepN[k, n]
  , {n, 2, 7}
  , {k, 1, 12}
  ] // TableForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the requested 15th Lucas term in the 3rd order.

```
LnStepN[15, 3]
```

> ```
> 9327
> ```

Comment: thanks for helping me, you really are a pro at this :)

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at OEIS for more formulas:
http://oeis.org/A001644

```
Lucas3[n_]:=Last[LinearRecurrence[{1, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, n + 1]];

Lucas3[15]
(* 9327 *)
```

This is experimental, but seems to work:

```
Lucas[k_Integer, n_Integer]:=Last[LinearRecurrence[ConstantArray[1,k], Array[(2^#-1)&, k], n]];

Lucas[3, 15]
```