# Understanding recursion and role of replacement rule for recursion in Mathematica

Tags: recursion

From the book "Essentials of Programming in Mathematica" (Fibonacci numbers):

If we think of this sequence as a function, we would just change this to a functional definition.

> F(1) = 1
> F(2) = 1
> F(n) = F(n – 2) + F(n – 1), for n > 2

In this form, we can translate the definition directly into code. The condition `n > 2` is unnecessary because specific rules such as `F[1] = 1` are looked up before more general rules like that for `F[n]`.

```
F[1] = 1;
F[2] = 1;
F[n_] := F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]
```

---

#### Questions

1. What do `F[1] = 1;` and `F[2] = 1;` mean, and what they do? For me, it looks like we are calling the function that is not even defined yet and assigning it a value. I do not understand that.
2. How `F[n_] := F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]` and `F[1] = 1;` and `F[2] = 1;` are related to each other and how they influence each other?
3. Is there is another, better example to understand recursion in Mathematica?

Comment: Please read a documentation page ref/Set. `f[1]=` is mentioned in Details section as well as e.g. in Scope / lhs.

Comment: Those tutorials cover it even better: tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions, tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with recursion formula in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61050/how-to-deal-with-recursion-formula-in-mathematica)

Comment: @m_goldberg I think it is more "related" question than "duplicate". My question is more related to replacement rule role in recursion and the question you linked is more recursion in general type of question. But anyway it is nice to have the link you provided in my question.

Comment: I agree that it is not a duplicate. To this question a good answer would cover `DownValues`  and "everything is an expression".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica is a term-rewriting system. You can image it as a set of replacement rules and a main loop that recursively applies these replacements to an expression until none of the replacement rules matches. So, in this sense, the recursion is immanent to the language design.

Executing

```
F[1] = 1
```

adds the replacement rule `HoldPattern[F[1]] :> 1` to the list of rules. (You can evaluate `DownValues[F]` to see which rules where attached to the symbol `F`.) From now on, whenever `F[1]` appears in an expression, Mathematica will replace it by `1`.

Moreover,

```
F[n_] := F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]
```

does not define a "function" in the usual sense; it adds `HoldPattern[F[n_]] :> F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]` to the list of rules. But as this rule consists of a transformation, `F` behaves like a function from now on.

Comment: 1. When we use the term "rule" in Mathematica, is it always means "transformation rule" or there are other kinds of rules too? 2. Does the last paragraph of your answer true for every other function in Mathematica too or it is true only in this particular example? If it is only true in this particular example please explain why.

Comment: @vasili111 There _are_ other tupes of functions in Mathematica, for example `Function` (also called "pure function"), `CompiledFuntion` (produced by `Compile`).

Comment: @vasili111 Rules (see `Rule`) can also occur in the definition of `Association`s, `Graph`s, and `SparseArray`s or for specifying options. In this case, the term "transformation rule" might not be appropriate.

Comment: So, just to summarize, my code in the question means: IF calling `F` as `F[1]` or as `F[2]` return `1`. In other cases of calling `F` return result of `F[n_] := F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]`. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. That's right. One has to know that Mathematica will always prefer a more special pattern over a more general one. `F[1]` evaluates to `1` (and does not start an infinite recursion) because the pattern `F[1]` is more special than `F[n_]`.

Comment: So in recursion explicit transormation rules like `F[1] = 1;` and `F[2] = 1;` are used as stop point for recursion to prevent infinite recursion?

Comment: Right. Exactly.

Comment: As a side note: Global rules associated with function also can be seen by evaluating `? name_of_function` in our example `? F`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is coming from a different programming background of the OP:

> What do F[1] = 1; and F[2] = 1; mean, and what they do? For me, it looks like we are calling the function that is not even defined yet and assigning it a value. I do not understand that.

As Mathematica isn't a compiled language (though technically this shouldn't preclude anything), it lets you update definitions multiple times. It's quite type-agnostic, so it doesn't need declaration either. What happens here is when you run `F[1] = 1`, the C-code equivalent would be

```
int F(int n) { // no need for "int" type specification in Mathematica
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return F(n); // impossible in C, but simply returns unevaluated in Mathematica
}
```

When you then run `F[2] = 1`, the definition is immediately *updated*:

```
int F(int n) {
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  if (n == 2) return 1;
  return F(n);
}
```

Finally `F[n_] := F[n - 1] + F[n - 2]` gives

```
int F(int n) {
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  if (n == 2) return 1;
  if (n == anything) return F(n-1) + F(n-2);
  return F(n);
}
```

Parting thought: Mathematica has a notion of specificity of patterns. If you evaluate in reverse

```
F[n_] := F[n-1] + F[n-2]
F[2] = 1
F[1] = 1
```

the equivalent C-code would be

```
int F(int n) {
  if (n == 2) return 1;
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  if (n == anything) return F(n-1) + F(n-2);
  return F(n);
}
```

I.e. the definitions for `1` and `2` are reversed, but the least-specific argument case goes to the end. This can, however, be overridden.

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you.

Comment: "no need for "int" type specification in Mathematica" - indeed not needed, but it is useful to have argument checking like `f[n_Integer] := (* stuff *)`.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions for `F[1]` and `F[2]` are the initial (stopping) values for `F`. Without them, the recursion could not stop and would theoretically result in an infinite recursion (in practice stopped by value for `$RecursionLimit`).

```
Clear[F]

F[n_] := F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]

F[5]

(* $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of F[-2039-2].

Hold[F[5 - 2] + F[5 - 1]] *)
```

Consequently,

```
Clear[F]

F[1] = 1;
F[2] = 1;
```

For efficiency use [`memorization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

```
F[n_Integer?Positive] := F[n] = F[n - 2] + F[n - 1];
```

For a fuller definition, rearrange the terms and use a change of variables to obtain

```
F[n_Integer?NonPositive] := F[n] = F[n + 2] - F[n + 1];

Show[Plot[Fibonacci[n], {n, -5.2, 5.2}],
 DiscretePlot[F[n], {n, -5, 5}]]
```

[image]

For a complete definition, use [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[F]

RSolve[{F[n] == F[n - 2] + F[n - 1], F[1] == 1, F[2] == 1}, F[n], n]

(* {{F[n] -> Fibonacci[n]}} *)
```

The recursion without initial values does not uniquely define the result, i.e., different initial values will give different results.

```
Clear[F]

RSolve[{F[n] == F[n - 2] + F[n - 1], F[1] == 1, F[2] == 2}, F[n], n]

(* {{F[n] -> 1/2 (Fibonacci[n] + LucasL[n])}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful answer.

Comment: As a side note: Memorisation technique discribed above is also called "Dynamic programming". Also, Dynamic programming will entail some increased cost in memory, as the global rule base is expanded to include the new rules. Source, book: "Essentials of Programming in Mathematica", Chapter Dynamic programming.